# Advice with material selection for compression applications

Tags: print-material, material, print-strength

I am creating a punch and a base for an arbor press and because of the specific size need, I want to 3D print them. The most pressure that an area of the base and punch should endure is something between 30 to 60 MPa on a small 83mm2 area. Obviously the material shouldn't compress at this pressure. I know that steel is probably an obvious answer here, but I'm looking for the most cost effective solution and rather not overkill. I was wondering what material would you recommend that can endure that conditions.